# How do I write a function that passes arguments to functions within?

Tags: function, r

I am writing a function in R that will evaluate the fit of a model, but each model takes the same arguments. How can I avoid repeating the same argument to each call to a model?

It is probably more clear here, where the arguments

```
  data=data,
  na.action = na.exclude,
  subset = block == site)
```

Are repeated.

```
modelfit <- function(order, response, predictor, site) {
   if(order == 0) {
     m <- lm(response ~ 1, 
             data=data,
             na.action = na.exclude,
             subset = block == site)
   } else if (is.numeric(order)) {
     m <- lm(response ~ poly(predictor, order), 
             data=data,
             na.action = na.exclude,
             subset = block == site)
   } else if (order == 'monod') {
     x<-predictor
     m <- nls(response ~ a*x/(b+x),
              start = list(a=1, b=1),
              data=data,
              na.action = na.exclude,
              subset = block == site)
   } else if (order == 'log') {
     m <- lm(response ~ poly(log(predictor), 1),
             data=data,
             na.action = na.exclude,
              subset = block == site)
   }
   AIC(m)
 }
```

Additional suggestions for better approaches to this question always appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't call your data `data` - give it a better name that doesn't class.

Comment: @Gavin thank you for explaining this to me in your answer... would `d` suffice, or do you have other recommendations? `data` is just so convenient...

Comment: call it what you want - just avoid `data`. `data()` is a function for loading example data sets in R and a large number of functions have a `'data'` argument. Calling your data `data` will just add to the confusion. In my example, I used `myData` but normally I real data analysis tasks, I name the data frame something relevant like `pollen` or `chemistry` as the name tells me what is in the data frame.

Comment: From the wisdom of the R-Help list, `fortune(77)`: "Firstly, don't call your matrix 'matrix'. Would you call your dog 'dog'? Anyway, it might clash with the function 'matrix'. -- Barry Rowlingson".  The lesson is: avoid using names that mask common functions and try to use names that describe the contents of a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `...` idiom to do this. You include `...` in the argument definition of your function and then within the `lm()` calls include `...` as an extra argument. The `...` effectively is a placeholder for all the extra arguments you wish to pass. Here is a (not tested) modification of your function that employs this approach:

```
modelfit <- function(order, response, predictor, site, ...) {
   if(order == 0) {
     m <- lm(response ~ 1, ...)
   } else if (is.numeric(order)) {
     m <- lm(response ~ poly(predictor, order), ...)
   } else if (order == 'monod') {
     x<-predictor
     m <- nls(response ~ a*x/(b+x), start = list(a=1, b=1), ...)
   } else if (order == 'log') {
     m <- lm(response ~ poly(log(predictor), 1), ...)
   }
   AIC(m)
 }
```

You then call this function and provide the repeated arguments in place of `...`:

```
with(myData, modelfit(2, myResponse, myPredictor, mySite, data = myData, 
                      na.action = na.exclude, subset = block == mySite))
```

where `myResponse`, `myPredictor` and `mySite` are the variables you want to use that **exist** in your `myData` data frame.

Comment: I think that you would need to either use with`(myData, modelfit())` or `modelfit(2, myData$myResponse, myData$myPredictor, myDataa$mySite, data = myData, na.action = na.exclude, subset = block == myData$mySite)` see my answer for a workable example.

Comment: @David: thanks for pointing that out. The perils of not having a reproducible example to work with. I've edited my answer to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to clarify a point in Gavin's answer with a simplified example:

Here is a dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2),
                y  = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
```

Here is a function:

```
mf <- function(response, predictor, ...) {
  lm(response~predictor, ...)
}
```

Note that

```
mf(d$y, d$x1, subset = d$x2 == 1, data = d)
```

works, but

```
mf(y, x1, subset = x2 == 1, data = d)
```

does not.